# How to get the raw page source?

Tags: python, json, selenium

Consider a URL like https://groups.yahoo.com/api/v1/groups/concatenative/messages/300 . This is an `application/json` response:

[image]

I'd like to access the JSON from Selenium. (I'm using Selenium because I need to access private groups and I didn't want to deal with figuring out how to login via mechanicalsoup or something of the sort.) However, getting the page source gives me *the way the browser is presenting the JSON*, not the JSON itself:

```
>>> self.br.driver.page_source
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link title="Wrap Long Lines" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" /></head><body><pre>{"ygPerms":{"resourceCapabilityList":[{"resourceType":"GROUP","capabilities":[{"name":"READ"},{"name":"JOIN"}]},{"resourceType":"PHOTO","capabilities":[]},{"resourceType":"FILE","capabilities":[]},{"resource ...
```

Note that the JSON is wrapped in some HTML and pre elements.

How can I get just the JSON, directly? It seems hacky to get the contents of the `<pre>` in the `<body>` since I don't know how the browser may choose to represent this JSON response in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can send AJAX to get the json directly with JSExecutor. See example below:

```
driver.get("https://groups.yahoo.com/api/v1/groups/concatenative/messages/300")
driver.set_script_timeout(10)
response = driver.execute_async_script(
    "console.log('Start AJAX');" +
    "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
    "var http = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
    "var url = '/api/v1/groups/concatenative/messages/300';" +
    "http.open('GET', url, true);" +

    "http.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
    "    if(http.readyState == 4) {" +
    "        callback(http.responseText);" +
    "    };" +
    "};" +
    "http.send();")
print(response)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was looking how to download JS and CSS files in C# from the ChromeDriver and used this method! Only change was making sure to get the AsynchronousJavaScript time to 5 seconds because otherwise it times out after zero seconds.